# How does output for "good movies" at 0th row is calculated?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa4Zd.jpg)

How does for "good movies" it comes out to be 0.707107 , according to me it should be : 1/1*ln(5/2) = 0.91629 .

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
texts = [
    "good movie", "not a good movie", "did not like", 
    "i like it", "good one"
]
# using default tokenizer in TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, max_df=0.5, ngram_range=(1, 2))
features = tfidf.fit_transform(texts)
pd.DataFrame(
    features.todense(),
    columns=tfidf.get_feature_names()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `norm` and `smooth_idf` parameter. By default, both are true.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
texts = [
    "good movie", "not a good movie", "did not like", 
    "i like it", "good one"
]
# using default tokenizer in TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, max_df=0.5,norm=None,smooth_idf=False, ngram_range=(1, 2))
features = tfidf.fit_transform(texts)
pd.DataFrame(
    features.todense(),
    columns=tfidf.get_feature_names()
)
```

Output:

```
    good movie  like        movie       not
0   1.916291    0.000000    1.916291    0.000000
1   1.916291    0.000000    1.916291    1.916291
2   0.000000    1.916291    0.000000    1.916291
3   0.000000    1.916291    0.000000    0.000000
4   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

Be default, the formula used by sklearn to calculate idf is `log [ n / df(t) ] + 1`. So 0.91621 by your calculation and add 1 to it.

If you do `smooth_idf=True` (default), then the formula becomes `log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(d, t)) ] + 1`

The output of `tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, max_df=0.5,norm=None,smooth_idf=True, ngram_range=(1, 2))` is

```
    good movie    like      movie       not
0   1.693147    0.000000    1.693147    0.000000
1   1.693147    0.000000    1.693147    1.693147
2   0.000000    1.693147    0.000000    1.693147
3   0.000000    1.693147    0.000000    0.000000
4   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

> How 0.707107??

### If you see that for the first row we have 1.693417 (call it a) two times, hence l2 norm is sqrt(a^2 + a^2), which is sqrt(1.69 ^ 2 + 1.69 ^ 2) = sqrt(5.73349), which equals to 2.3944. Now you divide 1.693147/2.3944, you approximately get 0.707107.

Read this [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html)